# What is a bitcoin incoming transaction with value = 0.00000546?

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info, block

I wrote a script that downloads and parses blocks. I see a lot of incoming payments with value = 0.00000546. Any explanation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This output value corresponds to the [dust limit](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/86068/63872) that is imposed on bitcoin transactions.

Many of these outputs may have been generated as a [dust attack](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/81508/63872) to de-anonymize users/ addresses.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Chytrik's mention of a dust attack, dust limit transactions are also used heavily by the Omni Layer to identify the recipient of an omni asset. Transactions such as those will follow pattern of one dust (or near dust) output, an OP_RETURN output, and a change output.

While dust attacks tend to create thousands of dust outputs in a handful of transactions, omni layer transactions will only create a single dust output per transaction.

Answer (score -1):

I would say that a [Dust Attack on Bitcoin](https://dust-attack.blogspot.com/2019/03/blog-post.html?m=1) is the most dangerous system that hackers use to steal Bitcoin. According to this article:
https://dust-attack.blogspot.com/2019/03/blog-post.html?m=1

Comment: I don't think dust attack can help steal bitcoin. May only be used to de-anonymize users.

Comment: It is in this transaction: https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/1d6580dcd979951bd600252b741c22a3ea8e605e43168f8452c68915c3ea2bf3
With the help of a dusty attack, a lot of coins were stolen.

Comment: How do you know it's stolen?