# After sweeping an address I've received a tiny amount on both the address I swept and the dest of the sweep

Tags: transactions, sweep

For some time now I've had a small amount sitting in a legacy address, and I finally decided to sweep it and send the amount less the fee to another address. I chose a small fee, to not spend more on the fee than on what was sent. The transaction got stuck, hovering around 20mb from the tip, neither getting evicted nor moved forward. So eventually I decided to try ViaBTC's free accelerator. This is the only step I took that I've never done before, and that's why I mention it. It worked well, and the next block they got included my transaction. However, just 30 minutes after it had been confirmed, I received an even smaller amount (3 digit Satoshi) to both the address I swept and the one I sent to. I don't have a problem abandoning a three digit Satoshi amount, but I'm puzzled by this. It's never happened to before, and the only thing I did differently was using the acceleration service. I have a hard time believing that they'd reward me for using a free service, but as I said, that's the only thing I did differently. Do they really reward using the free service, or should I suspect some kind of foul play?

Comment: That sounds like a "dust attack"

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Thanks. I've heard the term, but never bothered to find out more about it. Now I did. Considering that the info I found says that 546 or less is usually considered spam, and I received 547, I believe you're absolutely right. I'll abandon the address I swept and empty the one I sent to asap.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deanonymizing dust attack](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/81508/deanonymizing-dust-attack)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I believe it does.