# What is the reason for unusual stuck bitcoin transaction?

Tags: blockchain

I have my bitcoin wallet and there is the following situation:

1. There is a strange transaction with 200+ inputs to the wallet A which I don't know (with low amount and very low fee). These transactions are staying unconfirmed in the network.
2. There is then transaction from this wallet A with 70+ outputs and one of them is the address of my wallet. These transaction is small as well with low commission. They are unconfirmed by network as well.
3. After these unconfirmed transactions appeared I tried to send transaction from my wallet with reasonable amount and reasonable commission (around 50 satoshi) and this transaction has been staying unconfirmed for the last 24+ hours. Can the root cause be these weird small (with low commission) transactions to my walled? I tried to send another reasonable transaction from totally another wallet with the same 50 satoshi commission - it worked.

Could you please help me to understand what is going on and how to unblock my stuck transaction?

Comment: What is the value of the output sent to you from wallet A? If it is extremely small (ie, near the dust limit), you may be experiencing a dust attack. See: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/81508/deanonymizing-dust-attack . Your wallet may have used the dust-attack-UTXO as part of the unconfirmed tx you tried to send (and would thus require a higher fee-rate, due to it being a child-pays-for-parent type of situation).

Comment: Thanks @chytrik! From address A it was sent about 0.000863 BTC to 70+ addresses, one of them was mine and amount for it is around 0.000007 BTC - very small one. Does it look like a dust attack?
Though I though BTC transactions are confirmed independently. Why are these transactions to my wallet blocking outgoing transactions I sent after?

Comment: Can you confirm whether or not the unconfirmed transaction you are trying to send includes the dust UTXO as an input? Some wallets will use unconfirmed inputs when crafting txs, some will not. (& good wallets can simply ignore and lock all inputs below a certain value limit, to guard against such privacy-invading attacks). It is really just a UX decision made by the wallet developers. If the tx is using the unconfirmed dust input, then the unconfirmed transaction that sent the dust to you will need to confirm in order for your transaction to confirm.

Comment: @chytrik, thank you! Will take a look at the details you mentioned. One more question if you don't mind - in btc network all transactions are public anyway, as far as I know. If so, what is the additional information I can get with dust as anyway I can track addresses and normal transactions to understand how different accounts are connected?